# Failed to install gems via Bundler. remote: ! remote: remote: ! Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app remote:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am working with an app and wanted to deploy it on heroku but I was getting some error messages and a build failed on heroku.

Below is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org' 

gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',     '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

And the Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.2)
      actionpack (= 4.2.2)
      actionview (= 4.2.2)
      activejob (= 4.2.2)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.2)
      actionview (= 4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    actionview (4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    activejob (4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.2)
      activemodel (= 4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.2)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.3.pre1)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (3.4.0)
      columnize (~> 0.8)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2)
      slop (~> 3.6)
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.5.2)
    globalid (0.3.5)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.2.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    loofah (2.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mime-types (2.6.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.7.0)
    multi_json (1.11.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    pg (0.17.1)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.2)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.2)
      actionpack (= 4.2.2)
      actionview (= 4.2.2)
      activejob (= 4.2.2)
      activemodel (= 4.2.2)
      activerecord (= 4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.2)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.2.2)
      actionpack (= 4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
    sass (3.4.15)
    sass-rails (5.0.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    sdoc (0.4.0)
      json (~> 1.8)
      rdoc (~> 4.0, < 5.0)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spring (1.1.3)
    sprockets (3.2.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.9)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.3.0)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.5.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    web-console (2.0.0.beta3)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (= 0.7.3.pre1)
      railties (~> 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug (= 3.4.0)
  coffee-rails (= 4.1.0)
  jbuilder (= 2.2.3)
  jquery-rails (= 4.0.3)
  pg (= 0.17.1)
  rails (= 4.2.2)
  rails_12factor (= 0.0.2)
  sass-rails (= 5.0.2)
  sdoc (= 0.4.0)
  spring (= 1.1.3)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.9)
  turbolinks (= 2.3.0)
  uglifier (= 2.5.3)
  web-console (= 2.0.0.beta3)
```

And below is the list of output screen message after I run git push heroku master on terminal.

```
.
.
remote:        You have added to the Gemfile:
remote:        * rails (= 4.2.2)
remote:        * sass-rails (= 5.0.2)
remote:        * uglifier (= 2.5.3)
remote:        * coffee-rails (= 4.1.0)
remote:        * jquery-rails (= 4.0.3)
remote:        * turbolinks (= 2.3.0)
remote:        * jbuilder (= 2.2.3)
remote:        * sdoc (= 0.4.0)
remote:        * sqlite3 (= 1.3.9)
remote:        * byebug (= 3.4.0)
remote:        * web-console (= 2.0.0.beta3)
remote:        * spring (= 1.1.3)
remote:        * pg (= 0.17.1)
remote:        * rails_12factor (= 0.0.2)
remote:        
remote:        You have deleted from the Gemfile:
remote:        * byebug
remote:        * coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
remote:        * jbuilder (~> 2.0)
remote:        * jquery-rails
remote:        * rails (= 4.2.0)
remote:        * sass-rails (~> 5.0)
remote:        * sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
remote:        * spring
remote:        * sqlite3
remote:        * turbolinks
remote:        * uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
remote:        * web-console (~> 2.0)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to cryptic-ravine-9920.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/cryptic-ravine-9920.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Can someone please look in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does not that mean simply that your Gemfile/Gemfile.lock in heroku are out of sync? If `bundle install` modifies Gemfile.lock, you should commit that and then push to heroku.

Another problem could be too old bundler. `gem update bundler ; bundle install` would fix that problem, if that's an issue.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, there was some problem in the sync of files as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this to fix
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...

```
$ bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Gemfile.lock fix"
$ git push heroku main
```